# react native use facebook sdk og.likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native

this is my code

I use GraphRequest in react-native-fbsdk

```
export function likeFBPage () {
  console.log('click');
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    const likeFBPageRequest = new GraphRequest('/me/og.likes', {
      accessToken: getState().user.fbToken,
      parameters: {
        object: {
          string: 'http:\/\/samples.ogp.me\/226075010839791',
        }
      },

      // not working.. 

      httpMethod: 'POST',
    }, (err, result) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(result);
    });
    console.log(likeFBPageRequest);
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(likeFBPageRequest).start();
  }
}
```

I want an action that like a facebook page.

so use Facebook graph api. this is link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes

I don't know how to add json params...

Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: You can't. Use the like button

Comment: Thanks! @WizKid.  When I used the like button, I could not specify the style(width, height). So I have bypassed that way(use og.likes). yep. Is there any way to change the button style??

Comment: You can not like Facebook pages via og.likes. The _only_ way to like pages is via the official Like buttons Facebook provides. It can not be done via API.

Comment: Thank you! @CBore !